# Arc length of $\int_2^{\sqrt{x}} t^2 \sqrt{2t^4-6}\ dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I'm supposed to find arc length of $$F(x)=\int_2^{\sqrt{x}} t^2 \sqrt{2t^4-6}\ dt$$ on $[2,7]$. So here I go. I know it's given by $$\int_2^7 \sqrt{1+[F'(x)]^2}\ dx.$$ I believe $$F'(x)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}(\sqrt{x})^2\sqrt{2(\sqrt{x})^4-6}=\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}\sqrt{2x^2-6}$$ and that's how I obtain $$[F'(x)]^2=\frac{x}{4}(2x^2-6)=\frac{x^3-3x}{2}$$ So the arc length is encrypted as $$\int_2^7 \sqrt{\frac{x^3-3x+2}{2}}\ dx$$ I checked in WolframAlpha and it does exist, but boy I don't know how to attack this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The cubic factors as $(x-1)^2(x+2)$. So we want to integrate $(x-1)\sqrt{x+2}$. Let $u=x+2$.

Comment: Oooh, so simple, dang it. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. The thing about most textbook arclength problems, including this one, is that they are quite artificial. Change the $2t^4-6$ to say $2t^4-5$, and when you do the same calculation you end up with an ugly-looking function that does not have an elementary antiderivative.